# Activate python macros in QGIS 3.12

Tags: qgis

I might have tomatoes on my eyes, but how can I generally activate Python macros in QGIS 3.12.

Before, I used QGIS 3.8 and had no problems at all with that...

Answer (score 3):

In the *Settings - Options* menu, in the lower part of the *General* tab it is an option called *Enable macros*. You can choose:

- Never
- Ask
- For this session only
- Not during this session
- Always (not recomended)

Answer (score 2):

Also, you can do that from `Project -> Properties -> Macros -> Python Macros`:

[image]

The above will be project-based macros.